# In-app purchase, make google play UI transparent

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

As part of in-app purchasing I am starting an activity provided by the google play service using startIntentSenderForResult() as described in http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.

How do I make the started activity use a transparent background so my app is visible in the background with the in-app purchasing activity on top of it? The background of the google play activity is grey now.

I have seen that other apps (Babbel, used for learning new languages) use a transparent google play UI and I'm wondering how to do this.

Comment: With "grey" you mean it's like a dialog and the background is 'greyed out' but transparent? And now you would like it to be fully transparent?

Comment: Can you post current and expected images ?

Comment: having the same problem: I want it to be in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The activity you are starting is a part of google play services. Its not yours to customize. 
Besides, it's not a good idea to think of customizing it. Its better to have "Similar looking UI perform similar functions" across applications. Showing the default google play payment activity imparts a trust in the user that your payment is handled not by you as an app developer, but by google using their gateway which they know and trust to be secure.

Comment: The grey background effect is caused by an instance of Crosswalk which suspends function (I assume) when the google UI is shown on top of it. Thank you for your efforts. At the time where I wrote the question I could not understand what caused this.